# How to set precise size of QPushButton?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5

I have SignatureEditorForm class, which inherits QDialog class:

```
SignatureEditorForm(QWidget* parent_widget) : QDialog(parent_widget)
{
    resize(SIGNATURE_EDITOR_SIZE);
    setWindowTitle(QString("Signature Editor"));
    setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
    setModal(true);
    {
        QPushButton* const button = new QPushButton(QString("<"), this);
        const QSize BUTTON_SIZE = QSize(22, 22);
        button->resize(BUTTON_SIZE);
    }
}
```

It contains QPushButton which has size (width: 22, height: 22) and "<" caption.
I have such picture of this widget (SignatureEditorForm). QPushButton has size (width: 20, height: 20). How can I set precise size of button?

P.S. I tried to use setMinimumSize, but it has not effects.

[image]

P.P.S. this line button->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid black; background: white"); gives such effect (precise size)

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
QWidget::setFixedSize
```

This and other methods works fine to set exact size of QWidget.

But your problem is not in Qt, it in Windows Styling.

Actual size of widget is exact, but Windows reserve space on borders for animations, so it looks smaller than you expect.

To fix it you need to write own style like this:

```
button->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid black; background: white");
```

Or use any of styles available here:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gallery.html

Comment: I tried such code :  button->setFixedSize(BUTTON_SIZE); (instead of resize), but it has not effect

Comment: Maybe it works but looks visual not like 22x22 because of Styles. Try 66x66 or 11x11 sizes, is it looks different?

Comment: In the case of 11x11 I have 9x9 size, but in the case 66x66 I have 66x66 (precise size)

Comment: In the case of 24x24, I have 22x22 size

Comment: How do you measure size?

Comment: I measure bounding box of button (including any visible border pixels)

Comment: Try this and measure again: button->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid black; background: white");

Comment: I have precise size of bounding box (22x22)

Comment: Than your problem is in Windows Styling and not in Qt.
You can make own styles or use one of this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gallery.html

Comment: Thanks, I want use this style, so, I suppose, that just increasing size to 24x24 will solve problem (I know, it is bad hack)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
QPushButton* const button = new QPushButton(QString("<"), this); 
const QSize BUTTON_SIZE = QSize(22, 22);
button->setMinimumSize(BUTTON_SIZE);
```

or:

```
button->setFixedSize(BUTTON_SIZE);
```

Comment: I dont know about setSize method (I tried use setMinimumSize, but it has not effects)

Comment: There is no `setSize` method on `QPushButton`.